# RegEx: Validating Alternate text for image

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to set validation for an image alternate text, and here's what I think should be validated so far. It's a pretty simple RegEx, but I'm yet to start learning that topic..

- Double quotes
- < and > characters to prevent HTML input

Is there anything else you would add to this? 
Would text length ever be an issue?

I appreciate your help and if someone could provide this simple RegEx I'd be really grateful :)

Comment: What is the context? Is there any reason to allow characters other than alphanumerics, underscore, and space?

Comment: Well to be honest, the image can be anything from a product, banner, icon so I need to be pretty 'open' about it. What if someone wanted a dollar sign, dash, ampersand, percentage etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a good place to start for me. Max size: pick something sane, unless you want it to be valid to post a dissertation as an alt text - though it is probably possible. As for the regex to validate it's okay:

```
/^[^"<>&\\]{0,XXX}$/
```

where XXX is the maximum size you want. Or get rid of the `{0,XXX}` altogether and replace it with `*` to mean "zero or more". Syntax depends on language, of course.

Also found this, looked interesting:

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/alt.html

Update:

Yeah, you two make a good point. As long as the quotes used around the alt-text aren't themselves single-quotes, then they should be fine.

And as per other answers below, possibly also & and . Though you may need to be careful with how many slashes, whether they are before things that matter. And also, whether   and such things are allowed in the text itself.

Comment: Wow - that's a wicked article. I can't believe how much is being covered just on Alt text. Incredible. Back to my question though, I think it's safe to allow single quotes, otherwise -Hello I'm Marko- won't validate.. If I remember correctly, setting the length of the string is done via {1, 100} after the square brackets?

Comment: Not knowing the context, I wouldn't rule out `'` so easily, since people use it in contractions, and quite a few names contain it.

Comment: Also, I'm using this inside of Umbraco, so I think the script should contain the "valid" characters as opposed to the invalid characters. Can this be rewritten in that way?

Comment: it's not easy to put that directly into the html in some way that i know of, unless you edit it at display-time with javascript. but you can put it in your validator and suit to taste as you go.

Comment: are you trying to do the validation of length within the regex as well? if you don't need to, i'd recommend doing that with a simple string length check. ant with an elephant gun and all that... :-)

Comment: I do need it inside the Regex so I don't have to modify Umbraco and put in validation methods.. So, how can we re-write this so it *doesn't* allow the characters specified above. Is there a *NOT* rule we can use? Basically I want the regex to be the OPPOSITE of what's there now, since the only thing my field accepts now is "&<>\. Not quite the desired effect :)

Comment: There is a way to make it match 'not these characters.' You need a `^` after the `[` to negate the contents. Having it outside just makes it match the start of the string. So it should look like `^[^"<>&\\\]{0,XXX}$` Deleted my answer since everything I mentioned has been included here by now.

Comment: @kaestur: good catch! i forgot the ^ inside the [] - updated!